# Error Jekyll new blog Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

Jekyll is giving me the following error

```
$~/Documents$ jekyll new myblog
Configuration file: none
Building site: new -> myblog
/bin/jekyll:251:in `rescue in <main>': uninitialized constant Jekyll::FatalException (NameError)
Did you mean?  SignalException
     from /usr/bin/jekyll:249:in `<main>'
```

I'm using the versions:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- ruby 2.3.1p112
- gem 2.5.1
- Jekyll 3.1.6

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, following the guide on the Jekyll site and am hitting the same wall

Comment: I'd recommend uninstalling all versions of Jekyll, and deleting /usr/bin/jekyll, then `gem install jekyll` again.  It's possible that the binary is of a different version than the gem it calls.